# How can I make Ionic InAppBrowser integration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am beginner at angular JS and ionic framework!
I need to integrate a static web page inside my app using InAppBrowser; I tried to insert the code in home.ts file but I don't know what to write in home.html file!!
All I need the functionality of opening predefined webpage inside home.ts that appears as soon as I press home button in tab theme.
I would be grateful If some one helped me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: you need nothing in your html

Comment: I put that code from the documentation reference     import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }


...


const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');

Comment: How I display the website after that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include anything in your html-file. Only if you want to open the static webpage using a button in your app.

Just include plugin and the function in your home.ts-file with:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'
```

and add the InAppBrowser to your constructor like this:

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }
```

and finally declare your function with:

```
openBrowser(){
  const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
}
```

If you would like to open the static webpage at the startup of the app just add the openBrowser-Function to the ionViewDidLoad-Function which is being executed every loading the Home-Page.

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.openBrowser();
}
```

---

so your final home.ts should look like this:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser' 

export class HomePage {
  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.openBrowser();
  }

  openBrowser(){
    const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
  }

}
```

For more information check the plugin documentation: [click](https://web.archive.org/web/20210919205830/https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help. Now the problem in ios interface after firing the browser (Done button is not there , I tried to apply what was there in documentation but unfortunately I couldn't). Do you have any idea how to exit the inAppBrowser and returns back to main app?? thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I don't have the possibilities to try it but like I have the experience with it the done button has to be visible without any options exactly like in my code. maybe is the "done"-button on the buttom of the screen? dont forget to mark my previous answer as "accepted" and vote it :)